# Scrape Bing Image using Simple Html Dom

Tags: php, html, dom

I want try to scrape image from BING IMAGE SEARCH..

ex url : 'http://www.bing.com/images/search?&q=anime+one+piece'

I am usng curl & simpl html dom
Then my code like this..

```
$url = 'http://www.bing.com/images/search?&q=anime+one+piece';
$html = $curl->get($url);
$htmlx  = new simple_html_dom();
$htmlx->load($html);
```

What i need to do next is, how i extract data to get IMAGE ID, IMAGE URL, IMAGE POST URL, THUMBNAIL URL

So far, my write my code like this...

```
foreach($htmlx->find('div[class=imgpt]') as $article) {
  echo $article->outertext;
}
```

It's not work correctly.. because only show 3 result, like this _i.gyazo.com/1d0526f505b5eb8f6ed2f43d82f5a837.png

Answer (score 0):

you need to extract json from `m` attribute in `<a class="iusc"` and try not to use `simple_html_dom` it very slow, in my PC it taking time more then 30 second, while regex 0.000999 second

`simple_html_dom` solution

```
foreach($htmlx->find('div[class=imgpt]') as $article) {
  $m = $article->getElementsByTagName("a")[0]->getAttribute("m");
  $m = htmlspecialchars_decode($m[1]);
  $m = json_decode($m);
  printf('<p>Image ID: %s <br> Post URL:%s<br> Image URL:%s</p>', $m->cid, $m->purl, $m->murl);
}
```

`preg_match_all` (regex) solution

```
$html = $curl->get($url);
preg_match_all('#m="(\{&quot;[^"]+)#', $html, $imgs);
foreach($imgs[1] as $m){
  $m = htmlspecialchars_decode($m);
  $m = json_decode($m);
  printf('<p>Image ID: %s <br> Post URL:%s<br> Image URL:%s</p>', $m->cid, $m->purl, $m->murl);
}
```